# Docker build to run Dart app can't find pubspec.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, docker

Following the instruction in https://www.dartlang.org/server/google-cloud-platform/app-engine/run.html
doesn't work anymore.
During the docker build phase it can't find pubspec.yaml ( Using regular expression with wildcard * ).
I'm using boot2docker and docker 1.5 and the google/dart-runtime image.
Any solution to solve this problem in the deploy of a Dart application in Google Cloud?

```
INFO     2015-03-08 14:41:12,215 containers.py:280] Step onbuild-0 : ADD pubspec.* /app/
ERROR    2015-03-08 14:41:12,244 containers.py:283] pubspec.*: no such file or directory
INFO     2015-03-08 14:41:12,244 containers.py:292] --------------------------------------------------------
ERROR    2015-03-08 14:41:12,244 instance.py:280] Docker build aborted: pubspec.*: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you use `ADD pubspec.yml` (without wildcard)?

Comment: As stated in the link I only add FROM google/dart-runtime
in Dockerfile, this image need to find the pubspec file. Adding "ADD" doesn't solve anyway

Comment: How does your project look like. Where is your `Dockerfile`, where is your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Dockerfile and pubspec.yaml are in the top directory

Comment: Please add contents of the relevant files to your question and work on fomatting your question for readability (use the 'quote' and 'code' buttons to make things stand out or be fixed-width).

Comment: I inserted the link with the steps and all the relevant files. Simply following the sample in the link don't produce the working app

Comment: Feels like a typo or stray unprintable character. If you copy and paste (don't type it) the `pubspec.*` text from that `ADD` command being run, and try `ls -l pubspec.*` in the local directory, do you see your file?

Comment: as stated in the link https://www.dartlang.org/server/google-cloud-platform/app-engine/run.html the ADD command is not in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Updating docker client to latest version done the work:

```
boot2docker stop 
boot2docker download
boot2docker start
```